# show a string 10 times using do while loop in assembly language

Tags: loops, assembly, do-while

**a code for printing string in while loop in assembly language:**

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
  msg db 0dh,0ah,'rashed$'
.code

main proc

    mov cx,10

    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    lea dx,msg
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

 while_:
        dec cx
        je end_while
        mov ah,9
        int 21h
        jmp while_

    end_while:

    mov ah,4ch
    main endp
end main
```

[image: execution of this program]

*i understand this while loop program but how to do that in do while loop???*

Comment: Where does the test come in a while loop? Where does the test come in a do...while loop? Adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  If you understand the code, then you must know how a while loop works.

Comment: but thats not works i tried

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your present solution of the **while-loop**: there's no good reason to display the string once in a separate step before starting the loop!

---

The **do-while-loop** is even simpler than the **while-loop**. Use it only when you know that there will be at least 1 iteration to perform!
For a **do-while-loop** you need to do the test at the bottom of the loop (**after** the 1st iteration). If the counter isn't exhausted you return to the top of the loop.

```
    mov cx, 10
do_while_:
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    dec cx
    jnz do_while_
```

As before, no need for a separate display before the loop.